# How to generate highest voltage possible without sparking?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, design, high-voltage

I need to precisely control high voltage in order to maximize the corona discharge zone while preventing arcing for a physics apparatus. The actual voltage when the corona breaks down will vary depending on environmental factors such as humidity, pressure, and contaminants in the air so the circuit would need to gradually ramp up the voltage until the point of arcing (indicated by sudden resistance drop / current spike) and then depending on the reaction time of the circuit either back off slightly on the voltage to arrest the spark formation - or else cut the voltage all the way back to zero, wait for the ionized path to dissipate and then ramp up to just below the established breakdown voltage.

This is exactly like keeping a capacitor teetering on the edge of its breakdown voltage - except if it does breakdown we get to try again instead of having to replace the cap!

Is anyone familiar with any tried and tested circuits that would fit this application, Or else just some suggestions for keeping down the component count? - The apparatus will be using multiple units either running independently, or managed by a separate control board.

The spacing between electrodes would be around 10 mm  to 20 mm which I'm guessing could take up to 30 kV before the corona broke down.

Comment: Do you already have any plans on how to generate this voltage? Is it DC or AC?

Comment: The electrodes will be DC, and as for how I'm generating the HV am not sure yet - have been looking at Cockroft-Walton generators to multiply a lower voltage signal but this would still need the signal to be a few hundred to keep the number of stages down.

Comment: Keep the positive resistance higher than the negative resistance that an arc would produce. That way an arc would produce a self extinguishing voltage drop. Another idea would be to operate in a magnetic field, where any current formed by an arc would cause the length of the ark to increase, breaking the arc.

Comment: What you describe is a current source with a very high compliance voltage. It is not as simple to accomplish this using a voltage source as it is to require a constant current and let the voltage vary accordingly. To find the required current you can measure the I-V curve of the discharge for different environmental conditions and choose a point you like.

Comment: Corona and arcing both depend on the gas around your electrodes, and its pressure determines the breakdown threshold.   There's history dependence, of course; arcing changs the gas composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would really stop bieng nosy in the physics involved(**though its unclear why one wanna charge object to medium breakdown condition and stop due to arching and start all over again**)

Here where you can get started,you can apply many type of ionization sensor,some of them are very simple like pressurized Helium(`much better option here`) tube and [PM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) tube design try googling them.

To control the this tube with a circuit you will need a control logic,well if you do a deep study,you will see the physics behind these tube operation is the key for designing the controller.
The design is based on proportional design in ionization region where the charge in tube is the measure of voltage outside,ahead of it lies the G.M region but I dont think there is need of that.

As generating high voltage you must have something like Van De Graft,or some other classic device,it wont be hard for you to get a [Scintillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillator).


Well want a cheap Solution use Photo detector to detect spark but a less ideal solution,
thing that I wont use is thermal detectors,the error would increase a lot and may be you cannot reach peak value.

Where I cant Tell you the circuit until unless the motive and the fucntionality of design are known.

---

Thanks for making the queries clear ,this is what I think may help,
A device that could  generate charge, I would suggest you to make Van de Graft Generator becasue it has a very simple design,
[image: As You can see only DC two motors]

For more Help you can see these [how to make Van de graft generator](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Lightning-Wand-a-Handheld-Van-de-Graaff-Genera/)

This guy's approach is much better  [The Org van de Graft](http://www.instructables.com/id/900000-volt-Van-de-Graaff-Generator-using-cheap-p/)

**As you would Want to make it upto a certain voltage you will have to calculate the capacitance of the upper doom,which you may change as per desire.**
The working of device is Simple, you induce charge on the belt which is then spread on the doom using corona discharge.

There are other alternatives also,but I think this is the best, and has the most simple control mechanism of on off keying,

***You could use on the detectors I told previously Pm tube produces a pulse train which can be used to trigger switching process***
You can count the pulse set equivalent voltage to each frequency,
Compare this to the opamp,using a SETPOINT of Voltage and add a little voltage to SETPOINT in the next cycle until is in range of -10uC of the limit of Object ,depending on the medium in which you use the setup,as you can this is a little bit complex.

**Some Things about the circuitry I suggest that you use stepper motors of small step-size,If the current required by the motor is very high,then try switching circuit use a really to switch power lines ON/OFF ,If You have a background in power electronics you could also use Thyristors as switch,its better to use low current motors(700~850 mA) as for those with high current you will need to design a extra controller.**

---

If you are not able to afford a Scintillator, or PM tube,I can suggest you to buy a Cold cathode tube,like(tube-lights etc),you should be able to light them up if you keep you cathode ray in direction of field,it will light up if you have sufficeint voltage,
Now whenever a arch will occur voltage at Van de Graft will fall so  does the current in your tube,and you could use this to turn off the Vande Graft,and start again after some time(***As electric field per distance ,result in voltage drop you can get enough voltage to light up the tube***)
***Using the Van De Graft you can generate upto 500kV using right material and shape.***

Comment: There purpose is to generate a continuous ionic wind so an ionization sensor would be a moot point (any leakage current would be attributable to generated ions) - the circuit needs to track and hold on the sweet spot just before the ion avalanche that ends in a spark so that it can generate the maximum flow.

Comment: what are you using to generate charge..

Comment: Not sure yet, That's a big part of my original question. At the moment I'm doing some experiments using an old monitor flyback (~15 kV) in a circuit. For the end circuit was thinking of some voltage multiplier circuit - but am yet to find any designs that are meant to be variable output... This is one of the main aspects I'm hoping someone on the forum can advise me on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if I needed to do what I'm doing on a much larger scale then this would be the way to go. I'm actually looking to move minute charges and want a solid state solution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_fluid_accelerator - but I am using for a different application)

Comment: Sure,the only problem is that EFA is always in containment,and one that you have is a example,I believe for ionic wind you need to disassemble it,It has dangerous gases in it.

Comment: It will be inside a tube